# Open and create .lzh file in java

Tags: java, lzh

I want to open and create .lzh file in java. I find [jlha library](http://homepage1.nifty.com/dangan/en/Content/Program/Java/jLHA/jLHA.html).
But I can not find any examples of using this library.
Is there a similar library with documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [project page](http://code.google.com/p/jlha/) hosted on google code. There you can find at least one [example](http://code.google.com/p/jlha/source/browse/trunk/src/lhax.java).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "jlhafrontend" project on Sourceforge?

http://jlhafrontend.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jlhafrontend/jlhafrontend/org/jlhafrontend/